# How do refer to complete colum, where there is a value, in Excel

Tags: excel

How can I refer to complete column, where there is a value, in Excel (where I don't need to keep updating the last row number)

In Google sheets, I can do this with `=ARRAYFORMULA(A2:A)`. So for example on sheet 1 I have three rows:

```
A
Fruit
Apples 
Pears
Oranges
```

I create a new worksheet and copy the formula above in A1 and I get:

```
A
Fruit
Apples 
Pears
Oranges
```

Sure it must be simple but after a few searches I can't find the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Excel there are several ways.

Probably the easiest is to use a **Table** with structured references.  The ranges will auto-expand/contract as you add/remove columns or rows.

For a dynamic reference, it is best to avoid `OFFSET` and `INDIRECT` as these are volatile functions which will recalculate when anything changes.  They can really slow things down depending on the amount of data.

If you want to refer to the used range in, let us say, column D, you can use a formula:

```
=$D$1:INDEX($D:$D,LOOKUP(2,1/(LEN($D:$D)<>0),ROW($D:$D)))
```

The `LOOKUP` function will return the row number of the last entry in column D that has any content.

You can also easily make this a `Named` formula, and use that `Name` in your worksheet formulas.

Answer (score 0):

To get this to work I had to create a formula to get the last row number and cancatanate this to the cell references I want to return.  Then stick this into a named region (myRange)

myRange
="A1:A" & ROW(OFFSET(worksheet1!A1,COUNTA(Results!A:A)-1,0))

Then use this named range in the follow formula:

in worksheet 2:
=IF(INDEX(INDIRECT(myRange),0)=0,"",INDEX(INDIRECT(myRange),0))

Semes a bit more complicated than the google sheets verison but it works.